# Wavesurfer not working with ionic 2 android

Tags: android, ionic2, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to use the [WaveSurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) javascript library in my Ionic 2 application.

I put the *min.js* below my *www* folder, then i import it in the *index.html*, and i declared the *WaveSurfer* variable in my *.ts* file.

```
  initContainer() {
    this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: document.getElementById("container"),
        waveColor: 'violet',
        progressColor: 'purple'
    });

    this.wavesurfer.load(this.filePath + this.directoryName + "/" + this.audioFileName);    
  }
```

I initialize the container.

```
<div id="container"><wave style="display: block; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none; height: 128px; width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;"><wave style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; display: none; box-sizing: border-box; border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><canvas style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></canvas></wave><canvas style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></canvas></wave></div>
```

The container what has been created, so i think the import is working well.

```
  play() {
    this.wavesurfer.play();
  }
```

After i push the play button, nothing happens, and the container is empty.
So the question is, can i use this library to visualize my audio on **Android**?

Or I just made a mistake somewhere?

(By the way, i tried my "own" audio files, which have been recorded with cordova-audio-input (i tried with cordova-media-plugin too), moreover default rightones. All of them show empty container, and they do not start.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. Instead of using path, i create a base64 URL from the audio, with cordova file plugin (*readAsDataURL()*), and now it's working properly.

However the *ready* event does not work to me,

```
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    this.wavesurfer.play();
});
```

I just use it without the *ready* event, because i use it in a function, when the *wavesurfer* object has to be ready yet,

```
    this.wavesurfer.play();
```

Now it is working, and it is epic (although it is a little bit slow, when i tried it with a one minute audio, so if i record an eight hour audio that will hurt, but that is already an another problem).

Edit:
I have to fix myself, because the *on-ready* event is working, only i have to bind the global variable to the event somehow.

Comment: Yes, i accepted my answer so you can see now. Do you have any problem, or did you want to help? 

Comment: for me it's working well on browser and android, but not at all on iOS. Did you try with iOS platform?

Comment: Yes i tried, and worked to me Any error? Or how did you tried? Or create a question with code, error then i can tell you more :)

Comment: What about using an external audio file url from a website? Wavesurfer.js says you can do this, and I have it working on the browser - but the container and wave canvas isn't showing up when I run my Android emulator...

Comment: how did you send the result from readAsDataURL() into wavesurfer? can you share the code?